# Getting crash when move from on viewcontroller to VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one home screen. And i programatically create two button with action. One will go to sign up screen , and another will go to sign in screen.

I added the both sign in and sign up storyboard identity. But when i move from that home VC to sign in VC and Sign Up VC i am getting crash:

```
 -[ViewController pressSignUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbb3a72e3f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController pressSignUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbb3a72e3f0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Here is my code:

```
// create button 1
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , 50.0)];

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.0f green:155/255.0f blue:211/255.0f alpha:0.6f]];
    [button setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSignUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // title color
    [self.view addSubview:button];

  // Button Two
   UIButton* button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , 50.0)];

   [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.0f green:155/255.0f blue:211/255.0f alpha:0.6f]];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSignIn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // title color
    [self.view addSubview:button1];

    // Border color for one button
    UIView *leftBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 1, button.frame.size.height)];
    leftBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:237/255.0f green:211/255.0f blue:246/255.0f alpha:0.6f];
    [button1 addSubview:leftBorder];

    -(void)pressSignUp

    {
        UIViewController *secondViewController =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignUpViewController"];
        [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
        // Here You can write functionality

    }


-(void)pressSignIn

{
    UIViewController *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignInViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    // Here You can write functionality

}
```

Why i am getting that crash.It any possible to move to Another Vc.

Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to implement the parameter for the sender:

```
-(void)pressSignUp:(UIButton*) sender {
    }
-(void)pressSignIn:(UIButton*) sender {
    }
```

And maybe you did not set the identifier in the interface builder:

*It's under the Identity Inspector tab in IB. It's called "Storyboard ID". E.g.: SignUpViewController*